# recursive function returning 'None'

Tags: python, recursion

my code is:

```
nums = [1,1]
def fib(n):
    nums.append(nums[-1]+nums[-2])
    if len(nums)-1 != n:
        fib(n)
    elif len(nums)-1 == n: 
        return nums

print(fib(5))
print(nums)
```

I see that the function returns None though nums is not None.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing a `return` before the recursive call `fib(n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it please to

```
def fib(n):
    nums.append(nums[-1] + nums[-2])
    if len(nums) - 1 != n:
        return fib(n)
    elif len(nums) - 1 == n:
        return nums
```

Comment: why should a return statement be there when we are just calling the function again and not returning any value to calling statement?

Comment: Cause recursive function always need to return statement. As you see on the simplest example of recursion - factorial - you will see - return statement need to collect data after recursive finished.